# RAID 5 array not working after disk replacement?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup-restoration, hp-storageworks

We have an HP StorageWorks server with HP Smart Array P212. It has 2 SAS array configurations.

- Logical drive 1 which is a RAID 1 configuration
- Logical drive 2 which is a RAID 5 configuration

One of the drives in the RAID 5 configuration failed last week and was replaced with a new drive of the same model while the machine was turned off.

When the machine was up again, I started the rebuild action in the HP Array Configuration Utility.
This was 4 days ago. I now see in the array configuration utility that all the drives are working and no errors remain.

But I cannot access the data it used to contain.
When I look at the Windows Disk Management, I can see the drive but it's in a RAW format.
I have also rebooted the server, and when booting Windows, it wanted to run a checkdisk on the drive. I have done this. It took somewhere between 1 and 2 days to complete the checkdisk, but at the end, it stopped checking and froze.

This is our backup server, so if possible, I would like to restore the historical backup data. Could someone please advice me on what to do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chkdsk utility must help in order to restore the NTFS partition -> chkdsk X: (drive letter) /f /r 
If the diskpart already identify partition as RAW, you can use EaseUS to restore the partition and the NTFS should be available.